# How to add search engine to GeckoFx web browser?

Tags: c#, winforms, search-engine, geckofx

I am implementing a custom browser based on Geckofx, i wanted to add a search engine where you can type any word and it search your document for coincidences, similar to Ctrl+F

Is there already a way to do this in geckofx?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: This works in GeckoFx 29, it does not work in GeckoFx 45**

I know about one method that is not entirely satisfying - but maybe that will give you a starter info...

```
private void Find(bool backward)
        {
            string searchString = FindOnPageBox.Text;
            var field = typeof(GWB).GetField("WebBrowser", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            nsIWebBrowser nsIWebBrowser = (nsIWebBrowser)field.GetValue(TheBrowser);
            var browserFind = Xpcom.QueryInterface<nsIWebBrowserFind>(nsIWebBrowser);
            browserFind.SetSearchStringAttribute(searchString);
            browserFind.SetMatchCaseAttribute(YourProgramName.Settings.CaseSensitiveSearch);
            try
            {
                browserFind.SetWrapFindAttribute(true);
                browserFind.SetFindBackwardsAttribute(backward);
                browserFind.FindNext();
            }
            catch { }
        }
```

And then invoke it on btn clicks...

```
private void findOnPage_Next_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Find(false);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this post: [Find, HighLight, Scroll toText in Geckofx Web Page](http://www.a1vbcode.com/app-5916.asp).

Written with VB.net 2010. It also works in Vb.net 2017.

Currently I am using in Windows 10 and the latest Geckofx60 and is working. Perfectly not always as I wrote it when using XuLRunner but the original code is their to modify to perfection if so desired.